# Calling function from other app into main app

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get navigation bar to work across all apps. But i am not able to call the function from there.

this is my base.html.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- Main CSS file -->
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/main.css' %}">
    {% block style %} {% endblock %}

    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Chili Pili</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item btn-login">
            <a href="{url 'login.view.login'}" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="main">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to call the login function which goes to the login page in login app on main page url. Also I want to make the login function works across different apps. Therefore, I am not able to call the function here (in the example code provided). Is there any way I can call the login function here (in the example code provided). So, I don't have to create login page again.

Answer (score 1):

If your base.html say is in an app called pages, and the template path is **pages/templates/pages/base.html** you can do in all apps

```
{% extends 'pages/base.html' %}
```

Comment: Adding base page like that helps a bit. but still is there way i can call function across apps. Like after going to login page. I cannot access home page as its part different app